# How to give back Transaction status to the user using SQL Server 2012 in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions

I am doing migration of data using stored procedure and I want to give user status of migration process. For example if the backup has completed then signal the status of `BackUp Completed` and so on ....

Here is sample stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_Migration
    @id int,
    @camid int,
    @output nvarchar(max) output
AS
BEGIN
    begin try
    Begin tran
        /* 1: code for backup */
        exec SP_CollegeBackup

        /* 2: code migration */
        exec Sp_studentmigrtion

        /* 3: migration finished */
        commit;
    end
    begin catch
         rollback ;
    end
END
GO
```

I want to give user back a status update at every step

Comment: Write status in a table and let the UI read from that table

Comment: if you are in a transaction, i think you won't be able to track the changes in every step

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!